# Hukuhara and Generalized Hukuhara Diffrentiability

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know this question has no relevance to the analysis, but it seems some friends about all the information they contain mathematical topics. So please forgive me
I have a question about fuzzy differential which i say it.My professor says that my solution is wrong,but i believe it is right.According to papers and books related to this problem,which i read,my solution is right.
If you can, please send the correct answer for me.
Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R_f$ with $f(t)=(1,2,3)t$ be a function.
We're investigating whether or not the existing Hukuhara  derivative and generalized  Hukuhara derivative at $t_0 =0$ . According to definition:

\begin{align*}f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h) \ominus_H f(x)}{h}\\
 &=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{[(1+\alpha)(x+h),(3-\alpha)(x+h)] \ominus_H [(1+\alpha)(x),(3-\alpha)(x)]}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{[(1+\alpha)(x+h-x),(3-\alpha)(x+h-x)]}{h}\\
&=[(1+\alpha),(3-\alpha)]\\
&=(1,2,3)\end{align*}

And generalized  Hukuhara derivative is equal with  Hukuhara derivative.Can you tell me what is wrong?
If writing answer was too hard take a picture and send me the photo.so Thanks.

ganhard1372@gmail.com

Comment: Give a reference where we can find the definition of Hukuhara differentiability (this differentiability is not found "at the corner of the street")

Comment: so thanks...Mathematics of Fuzzy Sets
and Fuzzy Logic by b.bede ...